# @One-To-Many Parameter gets not recognized in request

Tags: java, spring-boot

(Not sure if title is fitting for my problem, please correct me if necessary)

I have a controller with a postmapping:

```
@PostMapping("/user")
ResponseEntity addUser(Users receivedUser, OauthGatewayUser oauthGatewayUser) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

    logger.info("POST-Request from user: " + oauthGatewayUser.toString());
    logger.info("PostMapping: Received User: " + receivedUser);
    userService.addUser(oauthGatewayUser, receivedUser);
    return new ResponseEntity(receivedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And I have a users class which can have multiple Islands assigned, so the classes look like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table
    public class Users {
        @Id
        @NonNull
        @Column(unique = true)
        private String id;
        @Column(unique = true)
        private String userHandle;
        private PrivacyLevel privacyLevelProfile;
        private boolean isBlocked;
        private Long lastActiveIslandID;
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Island> islands = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
        public Users(String id) {
            lastActiveIslandID = 0L;
            this.id = id;
            privacyLevelProfile = PrivacyLevel.PUBLIC;
        }
    
        public Users(String id, String userHandle) {
            lastActiveIslandID = 0L;
            this.id = id;
            this.userHandle = userHandle;
            privacyLevelProfile = PrivacyLevel.PUBLIC;
        }
    
        public Users() {
    
        }
    //Getters and Setters here
}
```

Island class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Island {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long islandIdOnDevice;
    private String name;
    private String islandFruit;


    public Island(String name, String userID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.userID = userID;
        }
    }

    public Island() {

    }
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

If I now send this as POST-request:

```
{"id":"baf539b0","islands":[{"islandIdOnDevice":0,"name":"test","fruit":"avocado","userID":"baf539b0"}]}
```

Then the spring controller logs:

```
INFO 11916 --- [.83-8083-exec-3] global: POST-Request from user: OauthGatewayUser { id = baf539b0, name = TestUser }
INFO 11916 --- [.83-8083-exec-3] global: PostMapping: Received User: user{id=baf539b0, name='', isBlocked=false, [], last active=null}
```

What I want is to receive the island as part of the user so I then can attach it in the user service.

Comment: It seem the jackson can't deserialize  data to Islands Object. From your log of "received User", i don't see islands object ... Can you add @RequestBody Map<String,Object> body as third parameter for debugging... to see if your userReceived match with body.

Comment: Adding @Requestbody in front of the incoming user solved the problem for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The one-to-many annotation specifies an association. It helps spring understand what to do with the collection. But it doesn't **'join'** you data in any way when you query it.

Try this:

```java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn( name = "id", referencedColumnName = "userId")
private List<Island> islands = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: If I add your line of code, this exception occurs when trying to run it: https://pastebin.com/4QduSLB9

Comment: It is saying that your table doesn't have a column to store the reference to the user in the island entries. Your 'island' in the database needs a foreign key column to know what user it belongs to. My JoinColumn line assumes there is a column named user_id on the island table to store the 'id' of the user in. Either add the member to you entity if you are letting your code generate the table or add the column to your database (in sql, or with the migration implementation you use, e.g.: flyway, liquibase, ...).